# discord.py bot random image from a folder but each file can only be shown once

Tags: python, image, random, discord, discord.py

I'm fairly new to python and I can't seem to figure out how to make this work. any help?

I'm trying to make a command that makes my discord bot display a random image from a folder. There are around 2000 images in the folder. I want everyone to be able to use the command only once. The images are all unique and I don't want people getting the same image. how would I do this?

```
# Import Discord Package
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


# Client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

# Display random image


# Command that shows Mintbot's version
@client.command(name='version')
async def version(context):

    myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Mintbot", description="Test version", color=800080)
    myEmbed.add_field(name="Version Code", value="v1.0.0", inline=False)
    myEmbed.set_footer(text="Work In Progress!")

    await context.message.channel.send(embed=myEmbed)

# Welcome Message
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    general_channel = client.get_channel(931259149260554283)
    await general_channel.send('Hello, Mintbot here!')

# Disconnect message
@client.event
async def on_disconnect():
    general_channel = client.get_channel(931259149260554283)
    await general_channel.send('Turning Off')

# Mintbot Version - Embed
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'what version is mintbot?':
        general_channel = client.get_channel(931259149260554283)

        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Mintbot", description="Test version", color=800080)
        myEmbed.add_field(name="Version Code", value="v1.0.0", inline=False)
        myEmbed.set_footer(text="Work In Progress!")

        await general_channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
    await client.process_commands(message)  

# Run the client on the server
client.run('mytoken')
```

Comment: Where is the code that shows an image? Hard to help when we can't see what you've tried or if you're getting errors what errors you are getting.

Comment: your missing the code to import dotenv and read the .env file containing the token, the program wont work without a valid bot token

Comment: @verumIgnis More likely than not, the token argument for `client.run` was just set to what it is for the purposes of this post. Plus, the token doesn't strictly need to be read from a `.env`; that is just one of several ways to access it.

Comment: the bot already runs fine. I changed the token message so that people can't get into my bot. All the things i tried so far have failed so I deleted it. I was hoping one of you guys could hep me out. I've only been coding for about a week now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a json file named " list.json ".

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import json
import random 

# Client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

# Reading images
directory = "images" # Change this to your folder directory without / on the end
img = []
total_img = -1
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
  img += [filename]
  total_img += 1

# Display random image
@client.command()
async def image(context):
  with open("list.json", "r") as f:
    sent = json.load(f)
  if not str("sent") in sent:
    sent = {}
    sent["sent"] = []
    with open("list.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(sent, f , indent=4)
    with open("list.json", "r") as f:
      sent = json.load(f)
  if not str(context.author.id) in sent:
    sent[str(context.author.id)] = True
    with open("list.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(sent, f , indent=4)
    data = sent["sent"]
    random_number = None
    tries = 0
    while random_number == None:
      tries += 1
      number = random.randint(0, total_img)
      if not number in data:
        random_number = number
      if int(tries + 1) == total_img:
        await context.send("All pictures has been sent")
        return
    file = discord.File(f"{directory}/{img[random_number]}")
    await context.send(file=file)
    sent["sent"] += [random_number]
    with open("list.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(sent, f , indent=4)
  
# Command that shows Mintbot's version
@client.command(name='version')
async def version(context):

    myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Mintbot", description="Test version", color=800080)
    myEmbed.add_field(name="Version Code", value="v1.0.0", inline=False)
    myEmbed.set_footer(text="Work In Progress!")

    await context.message.channel.send(embed=myEmbed)

# Welcome Message
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    general_channel = client.get_channel(931259149260554283)
    await general_channel.send('Hello, Mintbot here!')


# Disconnect message
@client.event
async def on_disconnect():
    general_channel = client.get_channel(931259149260554283)
    await general_channel.send('Turning Off')

# Mintbot Version - Embed
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'what version is mintbot?':
        general_channel = client.get_channel(931259149260554283)

        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Mintbot", description="Test version", color=800080)
        myEmbed.add_field(name="Version Code", value="v1.0.0", inline=False)
        myEmbed.set_footer(text="Work In Progress!")

        await general_channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
    await client.process_commands(message)  

# Run the client on the server
client.run(token)
```

Comment: Thank you man, I really appreciate the help! I have created the list.json file but it doesn't work. My bot still starts up like normal and all the old things still work but the image doesn't.

Comment: did you put " {} " inside the json file?

Comment: It works now! thank you so much man. But how do I make it so that every person can  only use it once?

Comment: You don't have to do anything for that. The pictures can only be shown once per user

Comment: The people in the discord are now able to spam the command and keep on getting images. but what I want is that every single person can only get one image

Comment: You mean they get a single image and can never use the command again?

Comment: yes exactly so that everyone can only use the command once

Comment: Alright I edited it, try it. Sorry for misunderstanding!

Comment: I'm getting an error. It says that commands is not defined.

Comment: I figured it out, it was my mistake haha I forgot to paste the imports back in.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, thank you!!